# missing Account, ManagerViewModel folders and ApplicationUser.cs class from my Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new with c# especially the core asp.net 2.1
so I'm trying to create authentication with my project for the first time and I add it and the tables of users appear in database

but in Models folder I'm trying to find the ApplicationUser.cs class but can't find it in order to add and edit columns of AspNetUsers table
also the folders of the AccountViewModel and ManagerViewModel in Models not exist
but when open the project in browser it works fine and there is login and register in it

I'm tried to create another project and include authentication with it but still same problem also I tried to build and rebuild project
so what should I do while in videos that I watch I find these folders and class in Models

Comment: They are not included in the templates anymore by default (from ASP.NET COre 2.1), to make upgrading of the templates easier. You can scaffold it though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: thanks a lot for good rescourse @Tseng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net core 2.1, the razor pages are included in the *Microsoft.AspnetCore.Identity.UI* package and not directly added to your app folders like in the previous versions.

If you need to customize a page, you can override the default implementation by following these steps taken from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project) on how it's done

> - From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
> - From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select Identity > ADD.
> - In the ADD Identity dialog, select the options    you want.
>
>   - Select your existing layout page, or your layout file will    be overwritten with incorrect markup. For example
>       `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for Razor Pages
>       `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` for MVC projects
>   - Select the + button to create a new Data context class.
> - Select ADD.

Comment: okay that's about customized the view if I understand you well but what about the database should I create the ApplicationUser.cs im Models by myself and add the new columns to it? or how can I make changes on the AspNetUsers table? @Marcus Höglund

Comment: @muklah: The `ApplicationUser` is just a regular class which inherits from `IdentityUser` and is/was meant to show how to extend it. Identity, out of the box, works well with the `IdentityUser` model and there is no need for `ApplicationUser` unless you want extend the model with your own properties

Comment: @muklah yes, the answer shows how to override/modify the Identity views. Tsengs comment abow answers your other question well:)

Comment: thanks a lot I understand now what you mean after read some documentation @Marcus Höglund